# btfs: Zstd vs lzo

Tags: linux, filesystems, linux-kernel, btrfs, compression

Linux 4.14 added support for [Zstandard (or Zstd)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zstandard) compression. Here is a summary of the algorithm taken from Facebook's [project website](https://facebook.github.io/zstd/):

> Zstandard is a real-time compression algorithm, providing high compression ratios. It offers a very wide range of compression / speed trade-off, while being backed by a very fast decoder (see [benchmarks](https://facebook.github.io/zstd/#benchmarks)). It also offers a special mode for small data, called [dictionary compression](https://facebook.github.io/zstd/#small-data), and can create dictionaries from any sample set. Zstandard library is provided as open source software using a BSD license.

The support in Linux is quite new, so there might be hidden bugs. But apart from that, according to the benchmarks, the algorithm seems to outperform [lzo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lempel%E2%80%93Ziv%E2%80%93Oberhumer) in terms of compression ratio without sacrificing too much in terms of speed.

For a good tradeoff between speed and compression ratio, `compress=lzo` is generally recommended for btrfs. Should that recommendation be changed to `compress=zstd`?

Comment: What is missing from benchmark that zstd uses much more  memory than lzo/gzip when compressing/decompressing.

Comment: My current understanding: If your system is not too constrained on resources (e.g., memory, single-core), you will not notice any speed impact to lzo, but the better compression is significant. I recently switched my disks (lzo to zstd) and see no downside. IMHO if your kernel (and bootloader) supports zstd, you should strongly consider it as the default choice.

Comment: @PhilippClaßen how exactly does one switch compression algorithms on a btrfs system that's already set to compress with `lzo` ?

Comment: @eternaltyro The arch wiki has a description: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Btrfs#Compression  In short, you first change the compression algorithm. That will affect new files. In a second step, you can force the recompresson of old files by running "btrfs filesystem defragment -r -v -czstd /"

Comment: Thank you, @PhilippClaßen. That worked. I defrag'd and changed fstab and kernel params in bootloader entries to have `compress-force=zstd:1` for my NVMe.